# how to take a list with range of values and convert into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, lambda

```
list=['1','matt','26','teacher','yes','2','tom','26','teacher','no','3','stuart','28','teacher','No']
```

How to pick first five values from list and make into a dataframe like this:

```
number  name    age   type      employed
1       matt    26    teacher    yes
2       tom     26    teacher    no
3       staurt  28    teacher    No
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.array(lst).reshape(-1,5), 
             columns=['number','name','age','type','employed'])
```

Output:

```
  number    name age     type employed
0      1    matt  26  teacher      yes
1      2     tom  26  teacher       no
2      3  stuart  28  teacher       No
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
edata =['1','matt','26','teacher','yes','2','tom','26','teacher','no','3','stuart','28','teacher','No']
n_rows = 3
n_cols = 5
data = np.array(edata).reshape(n_rows,n_cols)
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data.columns =['number','name','age','type','employed']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have divide you `lst` into evenly sized chunks in your case it's 5.

```
pd.DataFrame([lst[i:i+5] for i in range(0,len(lst),5)],
             columns = ['number','name','age','type','employed'])
```

To generalized it so it works with generators too using `iter`

```
it = iter(lst)
pd.DataFrame(iter(lambda: list(islice(it,5)),[]),
             columns = ['number','name','age','type','employed'])
```

Output:

```
  number    name age     type employed
0      1    matt  26  teacher      yes
1      2     tom  26  teacher       no
2      3  stuart  28  teacher       No
```